# Need help finding an under-voltage protection IC for 2-4 cells

Tags: batteries, protection

I've been looking for the last few days but I just can't find one. I've found a ton of single cell protection IC's but I can't find one that does the same for up to 4 cells. A stackable single cell IC would work so that I can set them up in series to monitor multiple cells, if something like that exists. I just need something that can read the voltage and when one of the cells gets to  ~3.3v, output a 3-5v analog or digital signal that I'll use as an input to a microcontroller. I don't have much space so the smaller the better!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a brown-out detector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the **Ricoh R5432, R5433, R5436, R5650**. All of these can protect 3, 4, or 5 cells but have a variety of other features depending on which you choose.

Comment: The R5650 looks like it'll do! Thank you so much!

Comment: @thebestcookie please can you mark my answer as accepted? Thanks

Comment: The R5650 doesn't seem to be well stocked anywhere. Mouser only has 100ish them.  Do you know of any others? I found the BQ294700DSGR but is overvoltage instead of under. Do you know of anything just like it that does undervoltage? Thanks!

Comment: If you need 100+ then you should be able to get Ricoh to produce them (around 13 weeks I think). Depends on your timeline.

The TI BQ2962 and BQ2961 do under- and over-voltage protection.

Comment: Ah, ok. The data sheets for BQ2961/2 only say over voltage. It does have an internal under voltage protection that will shut itself off but I don't believe it outputs anything when that happens. I'll keep looking for other IC's that are more readily available, if I can't find anything I'll use the R5650. Thank you for your help!